# Как распарсить несколько первых чисел из строки?

Tags: java

Нужно распарсить первые 3 числа из строки.
Есть вариант: как-нибудь с помощью регулярного выражения, но есть проблема в его составлении.

Пример строки: `String s = "225 5 50 name:Название";`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если в вашей строке данные разделяются пробелом, то можно преобразовать строку в массив методом `split()`класса `String`:

```
String s = "225 5 50 name:Название";
String[] arrayFromString = s.split(" ");
//выводим строки:
for (int i = 0; i < arrayFromString.length; i++)
{
    System.out.println(arrayFromString[i]);
}
//Выведет:
//225
//5
//50
//name:Название
```

Answer (score 2):

Это кончно странный вопрос, но регуляр вот так в java работают:

```
String s = "225 5 50 name:Название";
Pattern patern = Pattern.compile("^(\\d+)\\s(\\d+)\\s(\\d+)\\s.*$");
Matcher matcher = patern.matcher(s);
matcher.matches();
System.out.println("First number: " + matcher.group(0) );
System.out.println("Second number: " + matcher.group(1) );
System.out.println("Third number: " + matcher.group(2) );
```